# What this mobile icon in my status bar?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, notification-icons

[image: cant identify the icon next to my network speed indicator.]

I can't identify the icon (that looks like a mobile icon) next to my network speed indicator. What is it and what does it mean?

Comment: Rotation lock? Try turning on auto-rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the orientation indicator. This shows that auto-rotate is turned off and phone will stay in potrait mode only. Turning on auto-rotate will hide the icon or change it depending on your rom.